# Files not being uploaded to server using PHP script

Tags: php, file-upload, amazon-ec2, webserver

So Im following a simple tutorial/example on how to upload files to a web server using HTML and PHP. There are no errors and everything seems to work fine, but the file is not saved on the web server...

I'm using an Amazon EC2 instance.
**EDIT:**
I now have permission warnings/errors in my echo output as shown below, even after running chmod 777 on the directories

**index.html**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="test.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png","tiff");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
echo "Upload attempt...: " . $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"] . "<br>";
if ((($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/gif")
     || ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
     || ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/tiff")
     || ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
     || ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
     || ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
     || ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["size"] < 20000000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {

  if ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["error"] . "<br>";
  } else {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
    if (file_exists("~/upload/" . $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"])) {
      echo $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
    } else {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"],
                         "../upload/" . $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "../upload/" . $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"];
    }
  }
} else {
  echo "Invalid file";
}
?>
```

echo output

```
Upload attempt...: storeflyer.jpg
Upload: storeflyer.jpg
Type: image/jpeg
Size: 35.1708984375 kB
Temp file: /tmp/phpqq6J4C
Warning: move_uploaded_file(../upload/storeflyer.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in ../test.php on line 29 Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpqq6J4C' to '../upload/storeflyer.jpg' in ../test.php on line 29 Stored in: ../upload/storeflyer.jpg
```

Comment: check the return value of `move_uploaded_file()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `~/upload/` with a tilde and slash as path.

You should remove all of the tildes and slashes by using `upload/` as a relative path.

Or, as stated by `sonic720` in a comment: `/var/www/upload` this will differ from server to server, so yours may be something like `/var/users/www/public_html/upload` that is another option.

Use `upload/` if executing your script from the root of your server.

If executed from a sub-folder, you may need to adjust it to, and for example: `../upload/`

Also check for folder permissions. Either `0755` or `0777`, yet `0755` is safer to use.

- About: `__DIR__` & `BASE_PATH`

Consult: http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

---

**Edit:**

I noticed something else `echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";` that should read as `echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["error"] . "<br>";`

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help during production testing.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

---

Comment: I second that. The "~" character reflects the web user's home directory and should be avoided in PHP scripts. Typically, the web user's home directory would be /var/www/ or something similar where you cannot write files to.

Use `__DIR__` and setup a BASE_PATH for your application. Lookup some wordpress code and you can easily search for ABSPATH which is the same thing.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for the reply, so I changed the path to `../upload/` and also ran `chmod 777` on it. But Im now getting a `failed to open stream: Permission denied in ../test.php` and I ran `chmod 777` on that folder as well...

Comment: @Ray You're welcome Ray. Place `test.php` which is your upload handler I presume and create a folder called `upload` in your server's root. Also place your form in your root, while keeping all upload instances to `upload/`. You should be able to have success in doing that. Once that's been accomplished, you can consider starting to switching things around as needed.

Comment: @Ray I noticed something else `echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";` that should read as `echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["error"] . "<br>";`